# Word for "temporarily fix an issue with makeshift equipment waiting for a permanent solution" (Italian: tamponare)

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, translation, italian

What's an English word/verb for
"temporarily fix an issue with makeshift equipment waiting for a permanent solution"?

In Italian, we use *tamponare* (same as *to dab* in English) for this usage.

Here is a relevant sense of Italian *tamponare* listed in *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tamponare)*:

> **3.** *(figuratively)* to provide a provisional or makeshift remedy for a critical situation; to apply a bandage to 
> ***tamponare** un debito ― to **provisionally remedy** a debt*

Note: *Tamponare* is a verb in Italian, hence the request is for a verb, not for a noun.

Comment: There are quite a few expressions that would fit but, as with all single-word requests, an example sentence of the use of the requested word in context is required.

Comment: This question has relevant answers: [Phrase to describe a fix that doesn't address the underlying issue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346431/phrase-to-describe-a-fix-that-doesnt-address-the-underlying-issue) (although it's a slightly different question)

Comment: Answers at the first thread mentioned above include 'hack' and 'stopgap'. 'Kludge' is given at the second mentioned, and elsewhere.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The other answers are for requests for a noun; this question asks for a verb

Comment: @DjinTonic But all the answers are merely repeats, and 'stopgap' has 10 UVs here.

Comment: @DjinTonic But all the answers are merely repeats, and the noun 'stopgap' has 10 UVs here. 'Jury-rig' is given at [Is there a word for making a shoddy version of something just to get it working?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553841/is-there-a-word-for-making-a-shoddy-version-of-something-just-to-get-it-working/553844#553844) and  [the idiom used when a bad situation is not fully resolved ....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522000/the-idiom-used-when-a-bad-situation-is-not-fully-resolved-and-can-escalate-easil/522109#522109).

Comment: @DDS I've tried to make your question more clear by editing it if you don't mind. I've also added some direct translations (other than "to dab" that you've mentioned) which you can find in most dictionaries. Your question might still not be clear if you want to use it figuratively or not. Could you please include an example sentence and/or context? You can also mention why it is different from other similar questions linked. Please see the requirements in [single-word-requests] tag also.

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/349197/50044

Comment: If there is such a word, I suggest it is "bodge."

Meanwhile, I wonder what you mean by "same as to dab in English"? In English, "to dab" has nothing to do with fixing,  temporary or permanent. Does anyone doubt that?

Whatever Italians use tamponare for it is nothing like fix, temporary or permanent, nor "dab". Does anyone doubt that?

"tamponare" just possibly might relate to the English verb "tamp" in the sense of plug, but even that would be a huge stretch…

Answer (score 27):

**Jury-rig** for a verb; **kludge** for a noun or verb

> **Jury-rig** (v.)
>
> To erect, construct, or arrange in a makeshift fashion. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jury-rig)

> To assemble quickly or from whatever is at hand, especially for
> temporary use:
>
> *To jury-rig stage lights using automobile headlights.*  [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jury-rig)

Using the verb for anything makeshift may be more AmE. The OED limits it to nautical usage:

> **Jury**, adj.
>
> I. Compounds.
>
> 1. *Nautical*. Used in combination to designate parts of a ship put together or contrived for temporary use. Categories
>
> a.   jury-rig  n.
>
> b.   jury-rig  v.
>
> c.   jury-rigged adj.

---

> Etymology
>
> The phrase 'jury-rigged' has been in use since at least 1788. **The
> adjectival use of 'jury', in the sense of makeshift or temporary, has
> been said to date from at least 1616**, when according to the 1933
> edition of the Oxford Dictionary of the English Language, it appeared
> in John Smith's *A Description of New England.* It appeared in
> Smith's more extensive *The General History of Virginia, New-England,
> and the Summer Isles* published in 1624.
>
> Two theories about the origin of this usage of 'jury-rig' are:
>
> • A corruption of jury mast; i.e., a mast for the day, a temporary mast,
> being a spare used when the mast has been carried away. From French
> *jour*: 'a day'.
>
> • From the Latin *adjutare*: 'to aid'; via Old French
> *ajurie*: 'help' or 'relief'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging#:%7E:text=Two%20theories%20about%20the%20origin%20of%20this%20usage,been%20carried%20away.%20From%20French%20jour%3A%20%27a%20day%27.)

> **jury-rig; jerry-build; jerry-rig; gerry-rig.** The first is an authentic nautical phrase, dating from the early 17th century. Derived
> from *jury-mast* (= temporary replacement for a ship's broken mast),
> the *jury* part here has nothing to do with 12 peers deciding
> someone's fate. Instead, according the Barnhardt's *Dictionary of
> Etymology*, it probably derives from the Old French word *ajurie* ( =
> help) ... [Garner's Modern English Usage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Garner_s_Modern_English_Usage/mSjnCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=jury-rig&pg=PA541&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

---

For a modern noun, we have

> **Kludge** or **kluge** (n)
>
> A haphazard or makeshift solution to a problem and especially to a
> computer or programming problem
>
> *Just getting your documents into and out of the iPad is a kludge. You must e-mail them back and forth to yourself or sync to your computer
> using iTunes software. —Steve Morgenstern* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kludge)

> **Kludge** (v.)
>
> (informal) To build or use a kludge. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kludge)

---

> Both the *OED* and *Green's Dictionary of Slang* credit Jackson W.
> Granholm as the first person to use the term. In his 1962 essay "How
> to Design a Kludge," he defines kludge as "An ill-assorted collection
> of poorly-matching parts, forming a distressing whole." The *OED*
> calls it a "jocular invention." [Ace Pilkington et al.; *Science
> Fiction and Futurism: Their Terms and Ideas*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_Fiction_and_Futurism/a2VEDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kludge&pg=PT102&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

---

> **Jury-Rigging and Whatnot**
>
> Figure 10.1 shows one of my favorite examples of **jury-rigging**. Ian
> Wilkerson, a colleague in Sydney, had a leak in his roof and asked a
> journeyman friend to help. The man rigged a funnel attached below the
> leak, to a tube leading out the front door over a railing, drooping
> toward the ground, slowly draining. Finding that a lamp in his house
> was hanging too low, the man also slung the lamp cord over the tube,
> **jury rigging on jury rigging**. [Stuart Kauffman; *A World Beyond Physics: The Emergence and Evolution of Life*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_World_Beyond_Physics/VAuXDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=jury-rigged&pg=PA120&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> We continually **jury-rig** aspects of our outward appearance, persona,
> and achievements in order to gain the acceptance and accolades from
> others that we can't provide to ourselves. [Laurie Warren; *Wild
> World, Joyful Heart*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wild_World_Joyful_Heart/1R-wDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=jury-rigged&pg=PT97&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> But the most puzzling thing about it was that the whole thing seemed
> to be just **jury-rigged**–as if someone had done no more than a hurried,
> patch-up job to get the set back in working order on an emergency and
> temporary basis. [Clifford Simak; *The Big Front Yard*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Big_Front_Yard/CWd5CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=jury-rigged&pg=PT26&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

---

Examples of *kludge* outside of IT:

> The liberal state may therefore be thought of as a ***kludge***—an
> inelegant, workaround solution to the otherwise intractable problem of
> banishing the political means. It seems clear to me that we liberals
> don't know how to eliminate the political means altogether. [Jason
> Kuznicki; *Technology and the End of Authority*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Technology_and_the_End_of_Authority/NP_6DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kludge&pg=PA179&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> In light of these issues, perhaps we should think of increasing block
> rates as “policy **kludges**” that are “clumsy but temporarily
> effective” while ultimately leading to larger problems...  [Ronald
> Griffin; *Water Resource Economics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Water_Resource_Economics_second_edition/qUe6CwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kludge&pg=PA303&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> When we are young, often we rush and are tempted to **kludge**. We
> come up with a fix and think, “Eh, it's not perfect, but it'll do for
> now.” If you are not careful, as you get older, those quick fixes can
> become permanently fixed in your ways. [Twyla Tharp; *Keep it
> Moving*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Keep_It_Moving/nBgIEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=we%20kludge&pg=PA141&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

Comment: I immediately thought of _jury-rig_ when I read the question, but a brief search seemed to indicate that it was a purely nautical expression. I'm glad you have found evidence that this isn't so!

Comment: @KateBunting I think it's not often used broadly in BrE. It seems that mainly AmE dictionaries have the more general meaning. I'll add some examples.

Comment: jury-rigged, jerry-rigged: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/jerry-built-vs-jury-rigged-vs-jerry-rigged-usage-history

Comment: @Lambie is correct. It is quite common in American English, and in all contexts, not just nautical.

Answer (score 19):

take a [**stopgap**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stopgap-measure) measure

> A stopgap is something that serves a purpose for a short time, but is replaced as soon as possible

Comment: It's in the news today in the US, as Congress just passed a stop-gap spending bill to keep the government funded until they can complete the budgeting process for the next year.

Comment: *Stopgap* is also a verb.

Answer (score 13):

**Bodge**.
Army term often used to describe a quick fix on a piece or repair of equipment

Comment: Cf. [Tom Scott, Art of the Bodge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U).

Comment: Worth noting that this is primarily British English — at least, it’s common in the UK and not widely used in the US, in my experience.  Wiktionary confirms, marking it as “British, Ireland” [sic]: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bodge

Answer (score 8):

In computing, the words **hack** ([Merriam Webster — noun 6](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hack)) or [**kludge**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kludge) are often used. [**Patch**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch) (as a verb) is a more general term, although generally means a permanent fix in computing (thank you @BoldBen).

(Certainly not ‘dab’ in any sense. This is a translation of the use of tamponare to mean ‘absorb’ (liquid) — presumable swab a spill, or dab it if it is only small. The derived noun, *tampon*, is used in English in this way only in the specialist chemical sense, as its widespread use is in commercial female sanitary products to absorb menstrual blood.)

Comment: I would say that a _patch_ is a (supposedly) permanent fix for a piece of software. The fact that some patches introduce other faults which also need patching is a separate issue. A good patch is a proper repair, not a temporary fix.

Comment: @BoldBen — Correct. I thought of this after posting and thought I had stressed the non-computer aspect of this, but see now I only used the word general. Will edit.

Comment: Also we have the medical terms, *tamponade/tamponage*: to stop bleeding by blockage; also the condition, *cardiac tamponade*, abnormal pressure on the heart caused by pericardial fluid.

Comment: "Hack" as a verb can be used for this; I often tell my supervisor when the fit hits the shan "Hold on, let me hack something together to get things back up, then we'll both go down  to the people who should have prevented it and throw a temper tantrum for a proper fix"

Answer (score 6):

Mechanic here - you "duct tape it". Nobody expects that you will actually use duct tape. It's just a metaphor. A somewhat dated phrase is a bailing wire fix, but it doesn't verb as well. Again, nobody is expecting you to literally use bailing wire.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of metaphors for quick repairs along these lines: [band-aid solution](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/band-aid+solution), sticking plaster, papering over the cracks, etc.

Comment: They even use [tape to patch wings on airplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_tape).

Comment: Yes, PPP-T-60 tape, I still remember the MIL-Spec for it. I had Aircraft Battle Damage Repair qualifications back in the 80s. Also called 200 mph tape.

Comment: "Papering over the cracks", to me, more suggests a "fix" that just makes it look as if the problem isn't there, rather than something that actually addresses the problem. Similar to "sweeping under the rug".

Answer (score 5):

The verb  *tamponare* is used in Italian for temporarily repairing a leak  but it can also be used, metaphorically, in a situation of emergency.

- We **plugged** the leak using rags…
- In the meantime we need to find a **quick fix** until IT arrives

> **[quick fix](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quick-fix)**
> something that seems to be a fast and easy solution to a problem but is in fact not very good or will not last long:
>
> • People are still looking for the quick fix.
> • He warned against any quick-fix solutions.
> <sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

Comment: However, the OP in an edit, did specify they wanted a verb.  Someone can **do** *a quick fix*, so I might edit my post and clarify that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Repairs on the fly.
Makeshift repairs.
Jerry-rig it until later when we can afford the repairs.

Answer (score 2):

As a verb, [MacGyver](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/MacGyver) could work for a North American audience.

> To assemble or repair something by ingenious improvisation, using everyday items that would not usually be used for the purpose.

Comment: I'm British and this was the first thing I thought of, but possibly only because it's used in tabletop role playing.

Answer (score 1):

***to patch something up***

[Cambridge dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patch-up?q=to+patch+up)

> to repair something, especially in a simple and temporary way

*I patched up the old bike and got it working.*

Answer (score 1):

We have an almost identical idiom, a [*band-aid solution*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/band-aid-solution) (from the Cambridge English Dictionary)

> a temporary solution that does not deal with the cause of a problem:
> Tax credits given to students are merely a band-aid solution to the
> rising cost of getting an education.

Answer (score 0):

Codge, or bodge. to patch or cobble together. To make hastily or carelessly. YourDictionary.com, Wiktionary.